# Which branches of civilization deserve an overseer?

Tags: government, politics, civilization, medieval

In my story's political system, which is in medieval setting, the ruler of the country has a council, which is made of six people from the kingdom's six states. I would like them each to oversee a particular pillar of civilization (e.g. person from state A traditionally oversees commerce, while person from state B oversees law, etc.)

My question is: What would be the main "domains" to deserve a overseer?

Some extra details, the nation is an island about the size of Australia, which is uber religious, but where religion handles itself vua their own structure. Their greatest army's allegiance is to the church and its main purpose is to enforce peace among the states and fight piracy.

Thanks!

Comment: Is the army essentially a police force and external threat non-existent?

Comment: (1) [The army's] *"main purpose is to enforce peace among the states":* what do you mean by "states" in one medieval kingdom? Do you mean emperor instead of king and empire instead of country? (2) The meaning of the word "nation" has changed very much between the Middle Ages and the present time. In the Middle Ages a nation was simply the set of people speaking the same language; that kind of nations had no political dimension whatsoever, and nobody even thought that political boundaries ought to be made to coincide with linguistic boundaries. The age of nation-states came centuries later.

Comment: Looking at the [department list of any large city](https://www.lacity.org/your-government/departments-commissions/boards-and-commissions) will give you a lot of ideas, but without knowing where you want to take your story, this question is off-topic.  How will you judge the best answer?  Why would one state leader be assigned a department and another not?  You might want to read our meta post on [narrative necessity](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7281/40609).

Comment: Your question is not so much story-based as world-based. A structure of government ministries/cabinets is very dependent on a particular society and it's context. I.e., education can be counted as a separate domain, it be a part of religion, or a part of civil service (as in medieval China). The relationships of church and army you describe are already pretty unique for your setting that it's hard for us to guess how the people in your world count your priorities.

Comment: Alexander: yes, it's mostly a policing force, with other plot related tasks that are irrelevant for my question. External threats are minimal, except for a strong pirate presence along the coast.

Comment: AlexP: thanks for the heads up, I'll research better in order to name my political regions better, but for the question, I'd say (in today's terms) that the country has 6 states, which have a certain amount of counties. Each county has a representative, but the representatives for the six "liege" counties need to have an extra something, kind of like a smaller council. I though of them as ministers, but ministers of what? Tradition is huge in my setting, so I'd like that to be reflected as well

Comment: JBH: It is a narrative necessity to have a smaller council. Details would be overbearing for this post, but I'm basically just looking for a few titles to set a few people over others in my political system, so their voices are louder than most

Comment: Cumehtar: you are right, of course, but I'm early enough in my outlining that I'm pretty flexible on the type of civilization/economy that's going to be in place, so any suggestion is valuable

Comment: This is POB. One might as well say you need a ministry of silly walks and they'd be right.

Comment: Renan: Well, people have managed to be pretty helpful. Who knew?

Comment: @Garnovski, when you want to notify a user who has previously posted a comment of a response, use the `@user` format like I did with your user name.  You can only do this once per comment.  Narrative necessity means your story requires specific departments to complete plot arcs.  Asking for random "best guesses" suggests you're putting the cart before the horse.  Without telling us what your plot arcs are, we can in no way suggest meaningful options that you can judge a best answer within the rules of Stack Exchange.  Hence my close vote.

Comment: @Garnovski, this is embodied in our [help/dont-ask] when it states, "To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where … every answer is equally valid."  Please keep this in mind for future questions, it's a common problem because people tend to use the site for brainstorming, which is ill suited to Stack Exchange's format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're describing is in essence a [Cabinet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cabinet_(government)) structure within government. In countries with an elected parliament and prime minister, the cabinet is the body of ministers with portfolios that are considered important, more or less. So, for instance, there will be a treasurer, minster of defence, minister of foreign affairs, etc. in the Australian Cabinet, and of course other portfolios as well that can differ from time to time depending on the priorities of the day.

The same is true of other Commonwealth countries, which each keep ministers of specific portfolios under the cabinet umbrella. In these countries, the person responsible for the administration of these portfolios are non-elected officials called secretaries. This, however, has a different connotation in the US model.

In the US, the secretaries that essentially are there to support and advise the President are also un-elected, but their role is closer in function to Ministers in a Commonwealth democratic system. As such, it's the secretaries that in the US model form what we would call a Cabinet (although I'm not sure what term is applied in the US model of government).

There are two important points to draw from this; the first is that regardless of one's form of government structure the idea of advisors and administrators being responsible for a specific arm of the nation's governance is nothing new. The second (and most relevant to your question) is that the positions of a cabinet tend to change over time just as the priorities of the nation change.

This is a really important point; In Australia at the moment, there is a large national conversation going on about Climate Change, for example. But, the Federal Government does not have remit to act on Climate Change because it's not explicitly mentioned in the Australian Constitution as a Federal interest. So, there's a federal minister for the environment, and even a public service department for it, but essentially they act to ensure that the states all enact consistent legislation. If the minister for the environment was considered a cabinet position today (and I have no idea if that is the case or not) then it would be a different cabinet structure to that conceived by the fathers of Australian Federation back in 1901.

The point being, that only you can know what your cabinet looks like, how many people are in it and what their responsibilities are, because only you know what's important to your nation. But in general terms, this is a very good thing. Forcing a specific structure on your advisors and areas of responsibility means your nation is not capable of the flexibility required to stay relevant in a changing world of shifting international alliances, the disruption to existing economies brought on by technical advancement (think things like the Industrial Revolution) and matters that emerge in a society as it grows, like food or water security issues and climate change.

So what are your six cabinet members responsible for? The simplest (and best) answer is that they're responsible for the six most important and relevant aspects of good government that your nation faces.

At the outset, that will be things like infrastructure (read as taxation and spending), defence, etc. But, it could also include transport, public welfare, health, immigration, law enforcement, education, infrastructure, and many other important aspects of maintaining a country and its citizenry in good order.

Answer (score 5):

The top great officials in [Wallachia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallachia) and [Moldavia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moldavia) in the late Middle Ages were, in decreasing order of precedence:

- [Only in Wallachia] The Great [Ban](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ban_(title)), basically the viceroy of [Lesser Wallachia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oltenia) (the part of the country west of the Olt river).
- The Great [Justiciar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Justiciar) ("vel vornic" in Romanian), charged with running the judicial system, internal affairs and public order. (Well, whatever public order they had, not that it was all that much of it.) (In Moldavia they had two of them, one for the Upper Country and one for the Lower Country; this compensates the lack of a Great Ban.)
- The Great [Logothete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logothete) ("vel logofăt") or Chancellor, charged with running the administration, chancellery and foreign correspondence. (The link between those areas is that they involve lots of writing; it's the Middle Ages, writing is an advanced skill.)
- The Great Treasurer, charged with running the fiscal system.
- The [Protospatharios](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protospatharios) ("First Sword-Bearer", "vel spătar" in Romanian) charged with running the army. (Note that he was not the supreme commander, but more like the Head of the Supreme Staff. The supreme commander was the Prince, obviously.)
- The Great [Chamberlain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chamberlain_(office)) ("vel postelnic" in Romanian), tasked with running the political and administrative aspects of the princely court.
- The Great [Seneschal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seneschal) ("vel stolnic" in Romanian), running the operational aspects of the princely court.
- The Great Executioner ("vel armaș"), running the rudimentary investigative service, the prisons and, obviously, overseeing executions and forceful interrogations.

The Princely Council included the top officials, *former* top officials (e.g., "biv vel vornic" = Former Great Justiciar) and the greatest noblemen (where "greatest" means having most land), about some twelve people in total.

Answer (score 2):

I will try to give a most general answer from the data you've given.

From your description of the relationship of the state and the religion it seems to me, that your state is actually theocratic. If the army is loyal to the church and not to the crown, then, in essence, neither your ruler not his council are able to control the external policy. They can't make peace or declare war if they don't have the army to back that up. So I will continue from that assumption.

It means, in my view, that means that affairs of religion, war, defence, diplomacy and external relationships are not on the council. This way, the council can only be able to manage the internal affairs of the state (with the possible exception of trade).

From the most basic needs of the state, you should have some position or positions that oversee finance. Tax collection is foremost here. There will be taxes, tax collectors and people that oversee them and transfer those taxes higher up. There will be the expenses on running the state machine. So you will have a Master of Coin, Treasurer or whatever you choose to call him.

The existence of other financial ministries heavily depends on the laws of ownership in your state. If there state is also a landowner, you may have a separate position to manage those lands and workers. If the state owns some industry, there will be some sort of Head Artificer. If the state oversees the external trade on itself, you may have a separate position for that. If everything on that list is privately owned by citizens, then the state only controls it through taxes and tariffs - so see above.

The next big area are laws and judiciary. However it is composed, there is some judicial system in place, and people who are judging. Setting up judges and overseeing them is a separate position. A lot of things depend on how the laws function and are created. Legislation may be rolled with judiciary in one area (although that's pretty weird), or it may be handled by a separate ministry for legislature, or your ruler and his council, or even by the Church.

Enforcing said laws and keeping the internal peace can also be rolled into judiciary, or can be a separate area again.

Then there are the needs of maintaining the government apparatus itself. It may take at least one position, maybe even two, depending on how big your bureaucracy is.